# Previous page header spilling into next page

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer

[image]

How do I remove the previous page header? It is spilling into the next page. I want just the 'Acknowledgements' title to be in the center.

Edit: This is what the table of contents looks like:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}}
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{
\btypeout{Table of Contents}
\addtotoc{Contents}
\begin{spacing}{1}{
    \setlength{\parskip}{1pt}
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\contentsname
        \@mkboth{
           \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}
    \@starttoc{toc}
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
   \cleardoublepage
}\end{spacing}
}
```

The next page which is the acknowledgment page looks like this

```
\begin{center}{\huge{\textit{Acknowledgments}} \par}\end{center}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgments}

\cleardoublepage
```

Comment: Usually this means you forgot to do a `\newpage` (or a `\clearpage`\`\cleardoublepage` if appropriate) before changing the page style. But you should give a minimal, working example document so that we can see what is really going on.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the actual structure of your document, and what kind of headers you want on other pages, but try to start with this:

```
\begin{center}{\huge{\textit{Acknowledgments}} \par}\end{center}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgments}
\chaptermark{}
\pagestyle{plain}

\cleardoublepage
\pagestyle{fancy}
```